# Does Graphhopper embedded code start a web server on local host?

Tags: graphhopper

At present I have a graphhopper instances running on server and use API from java application. I was thinking on migrating to embedded version as described here https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.4/docs/core/quickstart-from-source.md for various reasons.

It is not clear to me yet if I go this way would it actually start a graphhopper server on localhost? I have used some other products by embedding in java app and many of these products don't start server to speed up the app.

Anyone has tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GraphHopper as a library or as a web service that is started on localhost.

Please do not use version 0.4 it is very old. Use the most recent - 0.10 - instead.